# Pycoin: How to send transaction?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, python, green-address, pycoin

There is a problem in making and sending transaction.
I got UTXOS by using **API**(`GreenAddress`), and from utxos I made a transaction. But calculated fee is always larger than one in original GA service.
Sometimes success to send transaction.
Sometimes, receives error like this `'Invalid signature'`.
I can't find out reason.
Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without looking at the code. Want to paste the relevant code?

When dealing with the GreenAddress api we generally sign using libsecp256k1 rather than pycoin (even when we use pycoin for other things)

For example see https://github.com/greenaddress/garecovery - it makes GA multisig transactions with pycoin and then signs them

Hope it helps!

Comment: I appreciated your help. This answer is great helpful to me.

Comment: Hi, Lawrence Nahum. I saw the project you teached me. There is also one problem. Sorry. From unspent transactions, How to make transaction and sign it? Pls help me.